# Element 'CompositeBoundField' is not a known element. (trying to extend BoundField server control)

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

VS2010, .Net 4.0

In trying to extend the asp.net BoundField server control, as described here:
http://iridescence.no/post/FixingBoundFieldSupportforCompositeObjects.aspx

I have created a class:

```
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace CustomControls
{ 
    public class CompositeBoundField : BoundField
    {
        protected override object GetValue(Control controlContainer)
        {
            object item = DataBinder.GetDataItem(controlContainer);
            return DataBinder.Eval(item, this.DataField);
        }
    }
}
```

I've registered it from my page:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="cc" Namespace="CustomControls" %>
```

...and on that page, I am attempting to use it like so:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridDataSource" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <cc:CompositeBoundField DataField="Application.ApplicationName" HeaderText="ApplicationName" />
    </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

However, I am getting a compiler warning:

```
Element 'CompositeBoundField' is not a known element. This can occur if there is a compilation error in the Web site, or the web.config file is missing.
```

And when I run, I get the error:

```
Parser Error 
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Unknown server tag 'cc:CompositeBoundField'.
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

I tried this:
http://blog.tentaclesoftware.com/archive/2010/07/21/95.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Register declaration, the Assembly is mandatory:

```
<%@ Register Namespace="CustomControls" TagPrefix="cc" Assembly="MyCompany.MyApp.WebApp" %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check that Assembly attribute contains the full strong name e.g.

```
   <%@ Register Assembly="MyCompany.MyApp.WebApp, Version=3.42.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=674cf0e5bf72fa08"
                TagPrefix="cc"
                Namespace="CustomControls"  @%>
```

In addition, you might run into problems mapping two assemblies to the same TagPrefix.  Don't do that.  It can cause unpredictable results, and may suddenly stop working.